# Group items of a list with a step size python?

Tags: python, list, iterator

Given an input list

```
 l = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

and group size grp and step step

```
grp = 3; step = 2
```

I would like return a list. Note the repetition at the end

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
5 6 7
7 8 9
9 10 1
```

or if

```
grp= 4; step = 2
```

The output should be

```
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
5 6 7 8
7 8 9 10
```

This is the code I came up with it does not do the cyclic thing.
But would like to know if there is a smaller or a simpler solution

```
def grouplist(l,grp,step):
    oplist = list()
    for x in range(0,len(l)):
        if (x+grp<len(l)):
        oplist.append(str(l[x:x+grp]))
    return oplist
```

Comment: To me the two examples conflict.  Please show one for step=1. Or is that what example 1 should be?

Comment: @Pynchia the two examples don't conflict. Both of them have `step=2` so the first number on the second row should be `3` which it is.

Comment: Why for grp 4 step 2 do we wrap back around to 1 instead of to 10?

Comment: OK, it would have been nice to explain what step is (an offset from the beginning of the group, I gather now)

Comment: on top of @wim comment why is there no fifth row in the second example?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake with the second example it should have been a 10 instead of a 1. And the is no 5 row in second example as no element of the original list has been left out. for Eg:- in  grp = 3; step = 2 the last row is printed because 10 had never been printed but is the original list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the step function in xrange or range depending on what version of python you are using. Then to wrap back around just mod by the length of the list like so

```
import sys

def grouplist(l,grp,step):
    newlist=[]
    d = len(l)
    for i in xrange(0,len(l),step):
        for j in xrange(grp):
            newlist.append(l[(i+j)%d])
            sys.stdout.write(str(l[(i+j)%d]) + ' ')
        print

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print grouplist(l,3,2)
1 2 3 
3 4 5 
5 6 7 
7 8 9 
9 10 1 
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 1]

print grouplist(l,4,2)
1 2 3 4 
3 4 5 6 
5 6 7 8 
7 8 9 10 
9 10 1 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks But I also have a follow up question.
I actually do this for strings and the output I get is in the form 
['0_1_125.jpg', '0_1_126.jpg', '0_1_127.jpg']
['0_1_126.jpg', '0_1_127.jpg', '0_1_128.jpg']
['0_1_127.jpg', '0_1_128.jpg', '0_1_129.jpg']
Do you know how I could remove the ' and the [] and commas ??

Comment: @ArsenalFanatic to me that looks as if it is a list of lists which you can get rid of the `' []` by printing them rather than printing the list itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
def grouplist(L, grp, step):
    starts = range(0, len(L), step)
    stops = [x + grp for x in starts]
    groups = [(L*2)[start:stop] for start, stop in zip(starts, stops)]
    return groups

def tabulate(groups):
    print '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in groups)
    print
```

Example output:

```
>>> tabulate(grouplist(range(1,11), 3, 2))
1 2 3
3 4 5
5 6 7
7 8 9
9 10 1

>>> tabulate(grouplist(range(1,11), 4, 2))
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
5 6 7 8
7 8 9 10
9 10 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

using a deque:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque



def grps(l, gps, stp):
    d = deque(l)
    for i in range(0, len(l), stp):
        yield list(islice(d, gps))
        d.rotate(-stp)
```

output:

```
In [7]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

In [8]: list(grps(l, 3, 2))
Out[8]: [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [9, 10, 1]]

In [9]: list(grps(l, 4, 2))
Out[9]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 1, 2]]
```

You can also join yield the islice object and decide what you want to do with it outside:

```
def grps(l, gps, stp):
    d =  deque(l)
    for i in range(0, len(l), stp):
        yield  islice(d, gps)
        d.rotate(-stp)
```

Output:

```
In [11]:     for gp in grps(l, 3,2):
   ....:             print(" ".join(map(str,gp)))
   ....:     
1 2 3
3 4 5
5 6 7
7 8 9
9 10 1
```

Or just with modulo:

```
def grps(l, gps, stp):
    ln = len(l)
    for i in range(0, len(l), stp):
        yield (l[j % ln] for j in range(i, i + gps))


for gp in grps(l, 4, 2):
    print(" ".join(map(str, gp)))
```

Comment: @Padraic...I was working for something like your answer but you surpassed me... awesome ... :)

Comment: The deque idea is nice.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham...Mind Sharing some resources about working with itertools and collections module..as I've been following your answers and I see that you are using a lot of their methods...thanks .. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
[(l+l)[x:x+grp] for x,_ in list(enumerate(l))[::step]]
```

does the trick in one line

Comment: However it should be noted that doing `l+l` _each iteration_ is amazingly inefficient!

Comment: l2 = l+l; [l2[x:x+grp] for x,_ in list(enumerate(l))[::step]]
solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

The package [`iteration_utilities`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities)<sup>1</sup> has a function for this kind of sliding window extraction [`successive`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/successive.html):

```
from iteration_utilities import successive
from itertools import chain, islice, starmap

def wrapped_and_grouped_with_step(seq, groupsize, step, formatting=False):
    padded = chain(seq, seq[:step-1])
    grouped = successive(padded, groupsize)
    stepped = islice(grouped, None, None, step)
    if formatting:
        inner_formatted = starmap(('{} '*groupsize).strip().format, stepped)
        outer_formatted = '\n'.join(inner_formatted)
        return outer_formatted
    else:
        return stepped
```

Applying this to your examples:

```
>>> list(wrapped_and_grouped_with_step(l, 3, 2))
[(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7), (7, 8, 9), (9, 10, 1)]

>>> list(wrapped_and_grouped_with_step(l, 4, 2))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9, 10)]

>>> print(wrapped_and_grouped_with_step(l, 3, 2, formatting=True))
1 2 3
3 4 5
5 6 7
7 8 9
9 10 1

>>> print(wrapped_and_grouped_with_step(l, 4, 2, formatting=True))
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
5 6 7 8
7 8 9 10
```

---

The package also includes a convenience class [`ManyIterables`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/ManyIterables.html):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import ManyIterables
>>> step, groupsize = 2, 4
>>> print(ManyIterables(l, l[:step-1])
...       .chain()
...       .successive(groupsize)
...       [::step]
...       .starmap(('{} '*groupsize).strip().format)
...       .as_string('\n'))
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
5 6 7 8
7 8 9 10
```

Note that these operations are generator-based so the evaluation is postponed until you iterate over it (for example by creating a `list`).

---

<sup>Note that I'm the author of [iteration_utilities](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities). There are several other packages also providing similar functions, i.e. `more-itertools` and `toolz`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution, which does not use indexes on the list while scanning it. Instead it saves the encountered elements to be repeated and concatenates them with the elements that follow.

```
def grplst(l, grp, stp):
    ret = []
    saved = []
    curstp = 0
    dx = grp - stp
    for el in l:
        curstp += 1
        if curstp <= stp:
            ret.append(el)
        else:
            saved.append(el)
            if curstp >= grp:
                yield ret+saved
                ret = saved
                saved = []
                curstp = dx
    yield ret+l[:dx]


l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for g in grplst(l, 3, 2):
    print(g)

for g in grplst(l, 4, 2):
    print(g)
```

produces

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5]
[5, 6, 7]
[7, 8, 9]
[9, 10, 1]

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9, 10]
[9, 10, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.5, [`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.windowed) supports a `step` keyword.

```
> pip install more_itertools
```

Application:

```
import itertools as it 

import more_itertools as mit

def grouplist(l, grp, step):
    """Yield a finite number of windows."""
    iterable = it.cycle(l)
    cycled_windows = mit.windowed(iterable, grp, step=step)
    last_idx = grp - 1
    for i, window in enumerate(cycled_windows):
        yield window
        if last_idx >= len(l) - 1:
            break
        last_idx += (i * step)


list(grouplist(l, 3, 2))
# Out: [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7), (7, 8, 9), (9, 10, 1)]

list(grouplist(l, 4, 2))
# Out: [(1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9, 10)]

list(mit.flatten(grouplist(l, 3, 2))))                  # optional
# Out: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 1]
```